# Quotient $G \to G/N$ induces quotient $H \to H/N$ by restriction?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$. Consider closed subgroups $N \subseteq H \subseteq G$ such that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Then restricting the quotient $$\pi_G: G \to G/N$$ to $H$ and applying the universal property of quotients gives us a morphism $$\varphi : H/N \to G/N$$ of algebraic groups such that $\varphi \circ \pi_H = \pi_G \circ \iota$ where $\pi_H : H \to H/N$ and $\iota: H \to G$ is the inclusion.

> Question: Is $\varphi$ an isomorphism onto its image?

I believe this to be true, but when translating the situation to rings of regular functions I would have to show that restriction $k[G]^N \to k[H]^N$ of $N$-invariant regular functions is surjective and I do not see why this is true. I read in Humphrey's book on linear algebraic groups that it suffices to show that $\varphi$ or $\pi_G \circ \iota : H \to \pi_G(H)$ is separable but I do not know how to do this either (my knowledge on algebraic geometry is quite limited).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to be careful with how you even define the quotient in the first place here (which probably also depends on how you define an algebraic group in the first place). As I recall, the quotient of $GL_n$ by its center does not behave nicely on restriction to $SL_n$ unless one treats the quotient very carefully (and it might not even then).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : I believe the problem with $GL_n$ and $SL_n$ with regard to quotienting out the center comes from $Z(GL_n)$ not being contained in $SL_n$. Note however that I assume $N \subseteq H$. I think that might make a difference.

Comment: Ahh, good point. It was just the first example that came to mind where I remembered quotients acting strangely (and being why one considers the group $PGL_n$ rather than $PSL_n$ often).

Comment: It seems that this is claimed in Jantzen's Representations of Algebraic Groups, 6.1. Namely, it says that for any group $G$ and any homomorphism $\varphi$ we can identify $G/ker(\varphi)$ with $im(\varphi)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Yes, we can identify $G/ \ker(\varphi)$ with $im(\varphi)$ when we think of all these guys as group functors. But then I do not know how this works in this situation where I am only considering the $k$-points. Maybe the question then becomes something like: Is the kernel (in the functorial sense) of $H \to G/N$ given by $N \to H$?

Comment: Yeah, I can never recall how much of this can fail to behave as one would expect when working over an algebraically closed field (as most of Jantzen's book works in as much generality as possible). If I get time I will have to see if he mentions this in his course notes, where he focused more on the case over a field.

Comment: This is true when $N$ is reductive: Since $N\subseteq H$, you know that $H$ is an $N$-invariant, closed subset of $G$. Therefore, $\pi_G(H)$ is a closed subset of $H/\!\!/N$. Since the image of $\varphi$ is equal to $\pi_G(H)$, the image of $\varphi$ is closed. Hence, $\varphi$ is indeed an isomorphism onto its image. The fact that the restriction $k[G]^N\to k[H]^N$ is a surjection follows by applying the Reynolds operator. I have no counterexample for $N$ nonreductive, off the top of my hat, but it feels to me like there might be one.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain : Thank you for your comment. There are some things I do not understand. First, what do you mean by '$H/\!/N$' and $\pi_G(H)$ being a closed subset of it? Secondly, the image of $\varphi$ is always closed (if $N$ is reductive or not), so how should this imply that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism onto its image? I believe I get what you said about the Reynolds operator. I still hope this might hold in general, but a counterexample would be great, too, of course.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: By $H/\!\!/N$, I mean the GIT quotient. It is precisely $\operatorname{Spec}(k[H]^N)$, i.e. the variety with coordinate ring $k[H]^N$. This is well-defined only if $N$ is reductive because a Theorem by Hilbert asserts that $k[H]^N$ is finitely generated in this case. The image of a morphism between affine varieties is not closed in general. You are right, however, the main argument is $k[G]^N\to k[H]^N$ being surjective, not the image of $\varphi$ being closed.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain : Ok, so the quotient $G/N$ is endowed with the structure of a linear algebraic group which has the usual universal property of quotients w.r.t morphisms of algebraic groups but  $k[G/N]$ need not be identical to $k[G]^N$... It seems that I misinterpreted a part in Humphrey's book. So my approach was flawed to begin with. What else could one try? Oh and by the way, I did not mean that an arbitrary morphism of varieties has to have closed image, I meant morphisms of linear algebraic groups (like $\varphi$).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain : After consulting Humphrey's book again (section 12 in Chapter IV), it seems to me that he really does prove that $k[G/N]$ and $k[G]^N$ can be identified, as $\pi_G^* : k[G/N] \to k[G]$ is injective and clearly maps into $k[G]^N$ as well as $\pi_G^*(k[G/N]) \supseteq k[G]^N$ from section 12.3. Now I am confused. Can you help me clarify this?

Comment: It is indeed true that $k[G/N]$ can be identified with $k[G]^N$. But note that we need to be careful here, as $G/N$ need not be affine (or is $N$ normal and closed sufficient for that?)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Yes, $N$ being a closed and normal subgroup of $G$ is sufficient for $G/N$ to be affine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a result that answers my question positively.

In Borel's 'Linear Algebraic Groups', Proposition 6.7 in Chapter II says, that given a $k$-group $G$ acting $k$-morphically on a $k$-variety $V$, then for $x \in V(k)$ and $G(x)$ the orbit of $x$ under $G$,  the map $\psi: G \to G(x), g \mapsto g \cdot x$ is a quotient map for the stabilizer $G_x$ of $x$ if and only if $\ker(\text{d}\psi_e)$ is contained in $L(G_x)$, the Lie algebra of $G_x$.

In our situation $H$ acts on $G/N$ and taking $x = e \in G/N$ we have $\psi = \pi_G \circ \iota$ and $G_x = N$. We have $\ker((\text{d}\pi_G)_e) = L(N)$ and so $$\ker(\text{d}\psi_e) = \ker((\text{d}\pi_G)_e \circ (\text{d}\iota)_e) = L(H) \cap L(N) = L(N) = L(G_x)$$ because $N \subseteq H$. Consequently, $\pi_G \circ \iota : H \to \pi_G(H)$ is a quotient morphism for $N$ as desired.